# What is the right way to persist javax.json.JsonValue in cassandra?

Tags: java, json, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a complex JSON to be persisted/retrieved from Cassandra

I intend to store **javax.json.JsonValue** or **javax.json.JsonObject** (which implements java.util.Map)

What should be the column data type in cassandra ?

I tried the following
From Cassandra defined my column as below
**profile_data map** // I can have it  as well

From Java, I create a JsonValue as below and try to set it to the column

```
    JsonObjectBuilder profileObjectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    profileObjectBuilder.add("name","vinod");
    profileObjectBuilder.add("email", "abc@gmail.com");
    profileObjectBuilder.add("city", "Chennai");
    profileObjectBuilder.add("Country", "India");
```

But during persist i get following error

```
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:line 1:267 no viable alternative at input 'India' (..."email":"abc@gmail.com","city":"Chennai","Country":["Indi]...))
```

**NOTE:** If i create a empty JsonObjectBuilder without any key/value then persist succeeds.

Please help.